# python multiprocessing wrap tornado.ioloop

Tags: python, multiprocessing, tornado

I am really new to python's multiple processing, and I have some notions about async call, yield and etc...the most basic stuff. And I came to this snippet, in which multiprocessing.Process wraps around tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance

```
    # Set up the tornado web app
    app = make_app(predicted_model_queue)
    app.listen(8080)
    server_process = Process(target=tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start)
    # Start up the server to expose the metrics.
    server_process.start()
```

It intends to start a tornado server as a server_process, but the code does not work. I got the error,

`OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor`

I have no experiences with both lib, and have no idea how to fix it. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you're trying to achieve?
Creating the app in the main thread and starting the IOLoop in a new process might mean the app won't be "available" in that process.
I would try to start the IOLoop in main thread and use something like ProcessPoolExecutor for CPU instensive tasks when/if needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unusual pattern - if you're writing a new app, I wouldn't recommend copying it.

If you're just trying to *run* an app that does this (looks like it came from [here](https://github.com/AICoE/prometheus-anomaly-detector/blob/master/app.py)), the problem is that IOLoops cannot safely cross process boundaries (on some platforms it can sometimes work, but not always). To rewrite this code to correctly create the app and IOLoop in the child process, you could do this:

```
def run_server():
    app = make_app(predicted_model_queue)
    app.listen(8080)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
server_process = Process(target=run_server)
server_process.start()
```

This way only the `predicted_model_queue` is shared between the two processes.

Comment: Ben, thanks for the answer. Can you explain how IOLoop.current() or IOLoop.instance() works? How do they determine the sockets related with 8080 to include in the IO loops? And when to use current() and when to use instance()?

Comment: `current()` creates an IOLoop for the thread if one doesn't exist and stores a reference in a thread-local variable. `app.listen()` calls `current()` by default, so it must also only happen in the child process. Always use `current()`; `instance()` was deprecated a long time ago (and is now just an alias for `current()`).